# How to replace every instance of a variable length value in a fixed length file?

Tags: regex, notepad++

In the below example - This is a fixed length file that I am looking to FIND any row that begins with "10" and has an "M" 9 positions later.  When these types of records are found, I need to replace just the first name with the word Test which is found 35 positions later.

```
10123456789M 00002345678                       Tom Jones                           123 Main St
10123456789A 00002345678                       Debra Sally                         123 Main St
20123456789M 00002345678                       Michael Sampson                     123 Main St
10123456789M 00002345678                       Jonathan Smith                      123 Main St
```

As described so far, I can achieve this with the following regex in FIND and REPLACE

```
^(10(?:.{9}M).{35})(.*?) 
(\1)TEST
```

The problem I'm having is that it is a fixed length file and using the above will mess up the starting position of the following address data.  See the below is my results.  Is there a way to find and replace a variable length value in a fixed length file using Regex in Notepad++?

```
10123456789M 00002345678                       TEST Jones                           123 Main St
10123456789A 00002345678                       Debra Sally                         123 Main St
20123456789M 00002345678                       Michael Sampson                     123 Main St
10123456789M 00002345678                       TEST Smith                      123 Main St
```

Comment: I think you need to search for `^10.{9}M.{35}\K\S+` and replace with `TEST`. Or do you mean you need to replace with `TEST` and add/remove spaces after the second column value to keep them same across lines?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Wiktor!  I like the use of \K\S+ , I wasn't familiar with these.  It seems that would make me not need to save what comes before the first name and use (\1) in my replace.  Though when I click Replace or Replace All it isn't actually doing anything, it just continues to find the next occurrence of the Find.

That said, you're correct, my real issue is maintaining the total number of characters including spaces in that field since TEST is going to be less or more characters than the first name it's replacing.

Comment: Well, it replaces, but it does not affect spacing after Field 2. See [this screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/ugBMsk2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex is not very suited for that exact purpose. The closest to what you might be able to use I can come up with is:

```
(^10.{9}M.{35}).{5}
\1TEST_
```

(use space instead of _)

to get

[image]

Unfortunately this will mangle the names. Essentially you capture all up to the name into `\1` and not capture the next 5 whatevers. Then you replace all with whatever was captured + TEST + Space:  `\1TEST`

```
10123456789M 00002345678                       TEST ones                           123 Main St
10123456789A 00002345678                       Debra Sally                         123 Main St
20123456789M 00002345678                       Michael Sampson                     123 Main St
10123456789M 00002345678                       TEST han Smith                      123 Main St
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Patrick!

I was hoping that wasn't the case as your solution is what I was doing and I was asked to not butcher the name field while still retaining the structure of the later fields in the file.  I suppose I may need to use something other than regex.

Answer (score 1):

I accepted Patrick's answer as it seems my specific problem doesn't have a solution using regex in notepad++.  That said, I ended up doing something different in my case so figured I'd share in case anyone else stumbles on a similar problem.

Since the name field has extra spaces padded after the last name, I decided would retain the first name and replace the last name using the following.  This assumes no full names are longer than a certain length or you're going to have a bad time regardless.

```
^(10(?:.{9}M).{35})((.*?) ).{12}
(\1)(\2)TESTLASTNAME
```

Results in:

```
10123456789M 00002345678                       Tom TESTLASTNAME                    123 Main St
10123456789A 00002345678                       Debra Sally                         123 Main St
20123456789M 00002345678                       Michael Sampson                     123 Main St
10123456789M 00002345678                       Jonathan TESTLASTNAME               123 Main St
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex was amazing correct only you missed was `\w+`
And with substitution why you captured it with `()`
Below is a fix for your regex,

Find what: `^(10(?:.{9}M).{35})(.*?)\w+`
Replace with: `$1Test` or `\1Test`